# Sensor data from Matlab Mobile without wifi

Tags: android, matlab

Is there a way to take data from Matlab Mobile without an internet connection? I have my computer and phone linked through USB and would like to use the GPS in my phone to keep track of the position of my car. Ideally the data would just flow from my GPS sensors to the Matlab App and then through the USB connection and into Matlab. I guess what I'm asking is is there a way to connect my phone and computer without using internet?

Comment: You start your post with "_I have my computer and phone linked through USB_", which sound like a solid base statement, then your final question is "_is there a way to connect my phone and computer (without using internet)_". At that point I'm lost, I don't even know what you are actually asking.

Answer (score 0):

They just have to be in the same network. If you are on the go just use your phone as a wifi hotspot and connect to your computer. No internet required.